# LibreOffice Page Number Bug?

Tags: libreoffice

I am trying to insert page numbers for a document written with LibreOffice. Everything works just fine until I add an offset (so that the counting starts from 7). I add the offset of 6. Works fine, except that the last 6 pages do not have the number shown (even though the footer field is there).

This is important for me. Please let me know what I can do

Comment: In what universe is this a programming question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Don't use the Offset](http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Edit_Fields#Offset) if you want to start with a certain page number. Instead, [edit the properties of the first paragraph](http://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Page_Numbers#To_Start_With_a_Defined_Page_Number) at the first page of your document. Go to Menu `Format` -> `Paregraph` -> `Text Flow` ->  `Breaks` -> `Insert` -> `With Page Style`. Now, you can specify a custom page number.

[image: paragraph properties for page numbering]

**EDIT:**

It seems that the "offset" feature [causes heavy confusion for many users](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org/+bug/118935). I can hardly think of a use case where the offest feature would be really useful. Especially, it isn't suitable to modify the page numbering in a consistent way: even if you set an offset, a table of contents still will use the "real" numbering, ignoring the offset.

If you want to modify the page numbering, for example to

- make Writer start with with any other number than 1;
- use different numbering styles for different parts of your document (preface with roman numbers, main matter with arabic numbers...)
- exclude certain pages from numbering

you should use **pages styles** and **page breaks**. Notice that a page break is a **property of the first paragraph "after the page break"**: it's this paragraph that holds the information that there's a page break **before** it, which page style to use after that break, and which page number to apply.

Regarding offset: You could use offset as a sort of cross reference to a page before or after the current page. But for such a scenario, the "real" cross reference feature is much more powerful than the offset feature.

Some more info on this issue:

- **[OOo Writer docs on page numbering](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Numbering_pages)**;
- [tips regarding page numbering by Hagar Delest from OOo forums](http://user.services.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1221#p4790);
- [extension to handle page numbering more conveniently](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/node/374);
- [handle blank pages](http://openoffice.blogs.com/openoffice/2009/07/the-simplest-approach-to-the-most-reliable-way-to-have-no-page-number-on-the-first-page-in-openoffic.html);
- [TOC and page offset](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=85884)
- [Tutorial for page numbering](http://www.8daysaweek.co.uk/forums/viewtopic.php?t=34)

Comment: Good workaround, but I think the OP's observation is probably a bug that the LO folks (and probably OO given the history) might need to know about.

Comment: @twalberg: I'm not sure but i think this is the preferred way - i've linked the relevant parts of the LibreOffice Writer docs.

Comment: Could be - maybe the offset is intended for a different purpose or something. It doesn't seem very well documented, at least in the help file...

Comment: Thanks for the info! It really helped. still...this "offset" thing is confusing...and I think it should be looked into by the devs.

Comment: After so many years I ran into this topic as well... find the docs for LibreOffice 6.4 here https://help.libreoffice.org/6.4/en-GB/text/swriter/guide/pagenumbers.html?DbPAR=WRITER#bm_id5918759

Answer (score 0):

I've been going batty trying to get proper page numbering. I have three title pages with a dozen normal pages, images inserted all over. A typical guide. After a day of following every imaginable path I can but come to the conclusion that either it's buggy or at the very least incredibly non intuitive.

What is confusing is how to decide that the footer (or page possibly) is an index , footnote, default or other as the footer is named one of those. Sometimes the footer would show up on page one and others not.

I started using Scribus since I'm used to typesetting tools. It however lacks too many fundamental features which makes it too much of a pain to work around them. (EMACS are just too much work to get into from scratch, plus I like to see what I will get.) Decided that most everything I need is in Libra Office and set out to create the guide. All worked out pretty good but for the darn page numbering.

OK, finally it works. I used format Paragraph and Text Flow, Breaks. Page Style allows me to set a page to some style. You'd think that Format Page Style is the way to go, but there is something very non intuitive about this business.

Never thought I'd get this working. I still don't have full understanding on how it is supposed to be used. My ramblings are probably not very useful either, but maybe it will show someone else that you CAN have title pages without a footer and start page count on the page that you want.